# Deserializing JSON data containing a varying number of parameters to C# (using Json.NET)

Tags: c#, json, rest, json.net

I'm trying to deserialize the following JSON response:

```
[{"pollid":"1", "question":"This is a test", "start":"2011-06-28", "end":"2012-03-21", "category":"Roads", "0":"Yes", "1":"No"} … ]
```

A problem arises, however, in the fact that the number of parameters following "category" can vary from 0 to 10. Meaning all the following are possible JSON responses:

```
[{"pollid":"1", "question":"This is a test", "start":"2011-06-28", "end":"2012-03-21", "category":"Roads"} … ]
[{"pollid":"1", "question":"This is a test", "start":"2011-06-28", "end":"2012-03-21", "category":"Roads", "0":"Yes", "1":"No"} … ]
[{"pollid":"1", "question":"This is a test", "start":"2011-06-28", "end":"2012-03-21", "category":"Roads", "0":"Bad", "1":"OK", "2":"Good", "3":"Very good"} … ]
```

I'm deserializing responses to objects of the following form:

```
class Poll
    {
        public int pollid { get; set; }
        public string question { get; set; }
        public DateTime start { get; set; }
        public DateTime end { get; set; }
        public string category { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("0")]
        public string polloption0 { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("1")]
        public string polloption1 { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("2")]
        public string polloption2 { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("3")]
        public string polloption3 { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("4")]
        public string polloption4 { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("5")]
        public string polloption5 { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("6")]
        public string polloption6 { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("7")]
        public string polloption7 { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("8")]
        public string polloption8 { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("9")]
        public string polloption9 { get; set; }
    }
```

My questions is: Is there perhaps a better way to handle the storing of a varying number of parameters? Having 10 class properties which may or may not be used (depending on the response) seems like such a "hack".

Any help would be truly appreciated!

Many thanks,
Ted

Comment: Have you considered redesign the JSON Object format and include these values as an array?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have control over the way the provider presents the data – I'm only able to consume it. (If this is what you were suggesting?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either hold the variable number of properties in and Array

Have something like

```
List<string> ();
```

where you put all of polloption1, polloption2 ...

Or you could deserialize the json to a dynamic type

```
dynamic d = JObject.Parse(json);
```

And access the properties which you know exist

```
d.pollid, d.start, d.category ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll try using dynamic types. I have a feeling problems might arise due to me having to use the [JsonProperty("0")] keyword in-order for C# to correctly associate JSON parameters with object properties.

Comment: Or keep the polloption1, polloption2 ... properties as a List<string>()

Answer (score 0):

> Is there perhaps a better way to handle the storing of a varying number of parameters?

You could deserialize into an [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) or `dynamic` e.g.

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();   
var result = serializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(json);
foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item["question"]);
}
```

Comment: Thank-you for your reply. I'll give dynamic types a try.